# Can the vim program description be modified?

Tags: microsoft-windows

I am running Windows 7 Professional.  I have used the context menu for each of several file types to specify vim in the "open with" field.  There are times I want to open the selected file with vim and times I want to open it with gvim.  So I have both vim and gvim in the context menu when I right-click a file.  The problem is that both vim and gvim have the same icon and the same program description -- "Vi Improved - A Text Editor", so they are indistinguishable in the list of programs from which to choose in the "open with" field.  And whichever one I last used is the one that appears first, so I can't just select based on their relative position in the list.  Is there a way that I can edit the description on each executable to make it distinct?

Comment: I may be wrong but I think this is off-topic: your question is about Windows not Vim. Also you might be interested in [this Super User question](http://superuser.com/q/688665/386795).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires you to edit the registry.

Run `regedit.exe` and navigate to the file extension under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`. Text files for example would be

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT > .txt
```

The `(Default)` data set will define the file type, `txtfile` in this example.

The next step is to navigate to the shell section of file type entry under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT > txtfile > shell
```

Create a new Key (right click on shell > New > Key) and name the key the text you'd like to see (Open Text with console vim). Make a new key under this and name it `command`.

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT > txtfile > shell > Open Text with console vim > command
```

Set the `(Default)` value to the command line string you'd like to execute. Use `%1` to represent the file argument

```
cmd /K "C:\Vim\vim.exe" %1
```

If you want to open a file in gvim you can ditch the `cmd /K` stuff and just run the command directly

```
C:\\Vim\\gvim.exe %1
```

Now when you right click on any .txt file you'll see a new menu option.

Unfortunately you'll have to create this entry under every file type you want a special menu for. If you are defining new extension types you can always group the file type together by setting the `(Default)`. So `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT > .txt` contains the same `(Default)` value as `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT> .text`.